# Javascript: Why doesn't (p+1)++ work?

Tags: javascript

Regarding

```
p = 0;
(p+1)++;
> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation
```

and

```
p = 0;
++(p+4);
> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation
```

I just got a bit of a surprise, as I expected postfix/prefix operators to be ok with working on the resolution of the expression (brackets have the highest operator precedence).

Could someone give me with a line or three to explain what is happening here?

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks for the quick responses, first answer marked as the answer. I feel I should also point people to the indepth [answer from @thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22803428/1903116) below

Comment: what is p here ?? a variable?

Comment: first try to convert `p` in integer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`++` increments the value of a variable, so it is larger than before. Eg:

```
var x = 3;
x++;
alert(x); // will show 4
```

For there to be any point for this, the expression to the left of `++` must be accessible and mutable, otherwise the increment would be possible. Eg:

```
3++
```

doesn't make any sense, as 3 is a constant and can't be incremented. We don't want this to be possible:

```
3++;
alert(3); // outputs 4???
```

This is why your expression doesn't work. Ie:

```
var p = 2;
(p + 1)++;
```

has the same problem as above. `(p + 1)` will evaluate to 3, and `++` can't change the value of the constant 3.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to increment `()`,  the `increment/decrement` operator can be apply on variable, try the sample code

```
(p++) + 1
```

OR

```
(++p) + 1
```

Comment: `(p)++` works too though, so your explanation is not very precise.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that when you write `p++`, that actually gets translated to `p = p + 1`. The operators `++` and `--` are convenience notation for incrementing/decrementing a variable for future use. But how is `(p+1)++` or `++(p+4)` supposed to be translated? Those sort of imply that `1` or `4` are being incremented/decremented for future use, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an expression like this

```
(expr)++;
```

These are the operations JavaScript will do internally

1. Resolve the actual object referenced by `expr`.

   This step is important, because you can even do something like this

   ```
   var a = {b: 1};
   ++a.b;
   a.b++;
   console.log(a.b);
   # 3
   ```

   Now, JavaScript has to resolve the actual object to be incremented. In this case, it will be `b` in `a`.
2. Get the value at the reference and convert that value to a Number.

   This step is also very important, because you may even have values like this

   ```
   var a = {b: '1'};
   console.log(++a.b);
   # 2
   ```

   JavaScript will try its best to get a number value, instead of failing immediately.
3. Increment the number.
4. **Store the new vale in `expr`**. This is step where your expression is failing.

   In your case `expr` is `p + 1`, when it is resolved the value would be just a numeral, whose value can never be changed. (You can never change the value of 1 to something else). So, after the incrementing part, when the new value has to be stored back, JavaScript doesn't find a valid reference to store it. That is why it throws this error.

   > ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

This error message is actually thrown from internal [`PutValue`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.2) method. The very first step goes like this

> ```
> If Type(V) is not Reference, throw a ReferenceError exception.
> ```

Reference: [ECMA Script 5.1 Standard Specification for `Prefix Increment Operator`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.4)

Comment: @AshleyCoolman Yup, having deeper understanding of the language will make us better programmers :)

Comment: Because it is new to me, I'd just like to emphasise the link you cited:
http://es5.github.io/
Being able to check the nuts and bolts of an error message seems like a great tactic for solving problems like my one above.